# How to get multiple selected list items values in dropdown toggle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Need to get all selected values inside dropdown toggle with out removing previously loaded value, Please help

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("Select...");
<Dropdown className="dropdown-groove">
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-secondary " id="dropdown-basic">
          {selectedItem}
          <label className="dropdown-label">Dropdown label</label>
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
            {" "}
            <Form.Check
              onClick={(e) => {
                setSelectedItem("List A");
                e.stopPropagation();
              }}
              className="checkbox-groove"
              inline
              label="List Item 1"
              name="group1"
              type="checkbox"
            />{" "}
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">
            {" "}
            <Form.Check
              onClick={(e) => {
                setSelectedItem("List b");
                e.stopPropagation();
              }}
              className="checkbox-groove"
              inline
              label="List Item 2"
              name="group1"
              type="checkbox"
            />{" "}
          </Dropdown.Item>
</Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-with-checkboxs-nvw3hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a function after setState in line 6

```
function toggleCheckbox(addItem) {
    if (selectedItem.indexOf(addItem) < 0) {
      setSelectedItem(`${selectedItem} ${addItem}`);
    } else {
      setSelectedItem(selectedItem.replace(addItem, ""));
    }
  }
```

and replace `setSelectedItem("List A");` with `toggleCheckbox("List A");`
then, List b & c is same way to replace.

[codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-with-checkboxs-forked-ov7mk2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks Buddy, 
"Select..."  wanted to remove if any items selected from list & also "Select..." should load back if we unselect all selected items :(

Comment: yes, you could add another conditional statements for "Select..."